# How to remove prettyprint classes from my code

Tags: jquery, pretty-print

I have a jquery variable which holds html code with google's pretty-print classes to stylize the code.

```
<span class="pln">
  echo </span>
  <span class="str">"$output"</span>
<span class="pun">;</span>
<span class="pln">
    echo </span>
<span class="str">"$my_code"</span>
<span class="pun">;</span>
```

I wish to remove those pretty-print classes. The output should look like this

```
echo $output;
echo $my_code;
```

I also wish to keep those line breaks and code formatting.

I tried to remove each span elements using jquery but its a tedious task. Is there a way to do it in a more productive manner.

Comment: In your code sample, why are `$output` and `$my_code` looking like variables (which shows in your intended result) but seem to be treated as string literal in prettyprint? (from the quotes around them and the class name `str` set to their `span`s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, assuming all the code is inside a div with specific class, and you want to replace the content, of course you can change these aspects easily:

```
// change to fit your case
var parent = $('.your-own-class');

var html = parent.html();
html = html
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,'')
    .replace(/(\s\s+?)/gm, '')
    .replace(/(\s+?\<+?)/gm, '<');

var tempElement = $("<pre />").html(html);
tempElement.find(".pln:not(:first)").prepend("\n");
var text = tempElement.text();

// change to fit your case
var output = parent;

output.text(text).css("white-space", "pre");
```

Working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Meligy/Ym2M8/

Please note the code is not optimized for best performance, if your real world prettyprint code is rendered differently from the exact code you have here, you can save some Regex parses and get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var text = $(x).filter('span').text();
```

It seems to work just fine:

```
> $(x).filter('span').text()
"
  echo "$output";
    echo "$my_code";"
```